# Qt Navigation Between Windows - Signal & Slot

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtwidgets

I have made a pushdown button and I want to navigate to loginscreen from there. I am using close() and show() on it. But now I don't understand where to write the filename of the window where I want to navigate from that window.

Mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: ***But now I don't understand where to write the filename of the window where I want to navigate from that window.*** Either do I. I don't think you gave enough information. I don't understand what you mean by: ***write the filename of the window***

Comment: In simpler words, i don't understand how to navigate. I read somewhere that we should use ```close()``` and ```show()``` from signals/slots but what after that? Where/how do I specify the window I want to navigate to? I posted the code in case in there's an alternative way for it @drescherjm

Comment: @a125 The problem has nothing to do with the QtCreator IDE but rather with Qt so it is unnecessary to use that tag. I recommend you read the information for each tag.

Comment: _I want to navigate to loginscreen from there._ Which _loginscreen_? The one of Windows? One in your own program? I cannot see any source for a login screen in your sample code. It's still very unclear IMHO.